# Mac Appstore adress

Tags: mac-appstore, ping, domain

I'm trying to do a ping and a traceroute to the Mac Appstore for some testing purposes. Does anyone know the address, where the store is hosted.

Thanks in advance.
Max

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not have just one server for hosting. I'm sure that they have many such servers all over the world.

You can find this information on [Apple's Support site.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201999)

[image]